# Browser got crashed, with continuous drawing path on google map?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, browser

I am drawing Real Time path on google map data are comming continuous manner. But after some time **browser have been crashed**. I am trying to remove 
data from array but problem is that all path get removed and I have to redraw it again. My Requirement is that remove data load on browser without temperig
current path, offcourse old path get removed (means till some distance from start point coulld be removed after removing data from array). Similar like pagination.
load only viewble area data and draw on map.Any guidence is very appreciable.thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Looks like it's a memory leak. Try first to profile by your chrome devtools what is happened with memory an objects in tab.

[Identifying a Memory Problem with the DevTools Timeline](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-memory-profiling#identifying-a-memory-problem-with-the-devtools-timeline)

2. Create some like codepen or similar page where we can look at your situation with javascript code.